# How to access property in viewmodel to view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have viewmodel and view i have return some API logic in viewmodel and getting one dictionary after some logic..i want to access that dictionary value from view for ex.

```
viewmodel.someDic
```

but for now every-time i am getting empty dic.

```
class Viewmodel: ObservableObject {
@Published private var poductDetails:[String:ProductDetail] = [:]

   func createItems(data: ProductRootClass) {
        var productDetils = [String: SelectedProductDetail](){
         //some logic
         productDetils // with some object
         self.poductDetails = productDetils
        }
    }
}


struct View: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel

  var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
           Text("\(viewModel.poductDetails)")
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            print("\(viewModel.poductDetails)")
        })
   }
}
```

I want to access this dictionary from view.

I tried accessing by returning productDetils from any function but get empty everytime.

may i know the way to access property from viewmodel to view?

Comment: Read about *ObservableObject/ObservedObject* SwiftUI view-model pattern.

Comment: I have updated question ..any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a class conforming to `ObservableObject` and a property marked as `@Published`

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {

   @Published var productDetails = [String:ProductDetail]()

   func createItems(data: ProductRootClass) {
        var productDetils = [String: SelectedProductDetail]()
         //some logic
         productDetils // with some object
         self.productDetails = productDetils
        
    }
}
```

Whenever the property is modified the view will be updated.

In the view create an instance and declare it as `@StateObject`

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

  var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
           ForEach(viewModel.productDetails.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
               Text("\(viewModel.poductDetails[key]["someOtherKey"] as! String)")
           }
        }
   }
}
```

I would prefer an array as model, it's easier to access

Comment: Thank you may know how to pass @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel() to init method, as i need viewmodel in my init method

Comment: You can declare `@StateObject var viewModel : ViewModel` and add an `init` method `init { _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ViewModel()) }`. But in my answer `viewModel` is being initialized anyway.

Comment: I tried but still getting empty because viewModel.poductDetails[key] is getting called before getting data

Comment: Never mind, it's called again when the data is assigned to the property. If it's still empty then there's something wrong with your dictionary. But again, map the dictionary to an array, this is easier to handle.

Comment: map dictionary to array means should i just assign dict to arrays first object? for my case its not called again ...please check my updated code

Comment: No, I mean `var productDetils = [SelectedProductDetail]()`. And if the key is important add another property in `SelectedProductDetail` and assign the key in the `map` closure.

Comment: can you please provide example?

Comment: This is beyond the scope of this question and needs more information about the type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the view model and make a proper model.

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var productDetails:[ProductDetail] = []

}

struct ProductDetail: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String

}
```

Now you can do `ForEach(model.productDetails)`

Answer (score -2):

You can make your viewModel as a Singleton.

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    static let viewModelSingleton = ViewModel()
    @Published var productDetails = [String : ProductDetail]()
    \\API logic}
```

Access this viewModel Singleton in the view

```
struct view : View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModelObject = ViewModel.viewModelSingleton

    var body: some View {
         VStack(alignment: .leading) {
             Text("\(viewModelObject.productDetails)")
      }
 }}
```